# TypeError: Need a valid target to patch. when trying to mock function return value

Tags: python, unit-testing

I would like to mock the sql_query response to True.

```
def is_valid_group_2_user(email, event):
    if sql_query("group_2_account_id", "group_2_account", "user_email_address", email):
        print("User email in group_2 table")
        return event
    else:
        print("User email not in service table")
        raise Exception("Group_2 is not present in group_2 table")

def sql_query(select, table, condition, variable):
    cursor = database_connection()
    sqlQuery = "SELECT " + select + " from " + table + " where " + condition + " = " + "'" + variable + "'"
    cursor.execute(sqlQuery)
    response = cursor.fetchone()[0]
    cursor.close()
    return response
```

I have tried the following test:

```
@mock.patch("lambda_function.database_connection", "cursor")
@mock.patch(""""sql_query("group_2_account_id", "group_2_account", "user_email_address", email)""")
    def test_is_valid_group_2_user(self):
        self.assertEqual(lambda_function.database_connection, "cursor")
        email = "test@email.co.uk"
        lambda_function.sql_query("group_2_account_id", "group_2_account", "user_email_address", email).return_value = True
        event = "event"
        self.assertEqual(lambda_function.is_valid_group_2_user(email, event), event)
```

But I am returning the following error:

```
TypeError: Need a valid target to patch. You supplied: '"sql_query("group_2_account_id", "group_2_account", "user_email_address", email)'
```

Comment: When mocking, you don't pass in arguments directly to `@mock.patch`, instead you add the `MagicMock` instance as a parameter to the test ( `test_is_valid_group_2_user(self, mock_sql_query)` ) and call the mock in the test body, along with any arguments.

Comment: @jfaccioni could you please expand on calling the mock/direct me to an example? Thank you for your help, I am new to both testing and python.